# Taking Records from Database Java

Tags: java, jsp, jdbc

I have a Table Like below

[image]

I run a Query to get Values in Table as Below

```
SELECT Id, UserName, UserId, Password, 
       CASE Status WHEN 1 THEN 'Active' ELSE 'Inactive' END AS Status 
  FROM users
```

Now I Java code for the Above Query is as below.

```
    String[] arrUsersList[] = new String[100][5];
    String[] arrUsersTem    =  new String[5];

    pstmt = conn.createStatement(rs.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, rs.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    rs    = pstmt.executeQuery(strSQL);


    while(rs.next())
    {   
        arrUsersTem[0] = rs.getString("Id");
        arrUsersTem[1] = rs.getString("UserName");
        arrUsersTem[2] = rs.getString("UserId");
        arrUsersTem[3] = rs.getString("Password");
        arrUsersTem[4] = rs.getString("Status");

        arrUsersList.add(arrUsersTem);
    }
```

My Question is

I know I should use two dimensional array for getting the values from Recordset. I also know I am Doing it wrong way.What is the right way of taking records from Result set for the above.

Is array right option or i should use ArrayList or Some thing else.

Thanks for Reply.

Comment: Thanks, Everyone Helped Me Every one Posted Answer.Confused which one to tick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java is OOP language, so common way is to create class describing entities of your table and form [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) with this class objects

```
class Account {

    private long id;
    private String userName;
    private String userId;
    private String password;
    private boolean status;

    // getters, setters
}
```

---

```
List<Account> accountList = new ArrayList();
Account account;

while(rs.next()) {   

    account = new Account();
    account.setId(rs.getLong("Id"));
    account.setUserName(rs.getString("UserName"));
    account.setUserId(rs.getString("UserId"));
    account.setPassword(rs.getString("Password"));
    account.setStatus(rs.getBoolean("Status"));

    accountList.add(account);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Reply I am new to Java So I should look for how to relate table with collections in java right

Answer (score 4):

You should create a User bean that contains fields for each of your database columns. Then create a List of User beans and do this:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
while(rs.next()) {   
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(rs.getString("Id"));
        user.setUsername(rs.getString("UserName"));
        //More fields here


        users.add(user);
    }
```

You will then be left with a list of Users rather than a confusing 2d array

Comment: Thanks for Reply. So the User after List<User> is Class Name Right

Comment: Yeah thats right. That is specifying the class of objects that will exist in that list. It is using Generics. search around  on Java generics if you wish to learn more on that

Answer (score 2):

Since you result set can be of any size, you should not use Array, you should use Collection (or any derived implementation).

First you should create a class that represent the tuple you are retrieving:

```
public class User {

  // fields
  private int id;
  private int userId;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String status;

  // constructor
  public User(ResultSet rs) {
    id = rs.getInt("Id");
    // the same for the other fields...
  }
}
```

Second and last, when iterating just create a new instance for each row/tuple, and add the resulting object to a collection that will grow as needed.

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
while(rs.next())
{   
   users.add(new User(rs));
}
```

Comment: I would avoid having your business domain objects (e.g. User) dependent on JDBC classes like ResultSet. Keep them separate.

Answer (score 2):

I would create a class User:

```
public class User {
   private int id;
   private String userName;
   private String userId;
   private String password;
   private boolean active;
   // getters & setters...
}
```

And then create Users like this:

SQL:

```
SELECT Id, UserName, UserId, Password, Status FROM users
```

Java:

```
List<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();

while (rs.next()) {
   User user = new User();
   user.setId(rs.getInt(1));
   user.setUserName(rs.getString(2));
   user.setUserId(rs.getString(3));
   user.setPassword(rs.getString(4));
   user.setActive(rs.getInt(5)>0);
   users.add(user);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while(rs.next()) {   

   account = new Account();
   account.setId(rs.getLong("Id"));
   account.setUserName(rs.getString("UserName"));
   account.setUserId(rs.getString("UserId"));
   account.setPassword(rs.getString("Password"));
   account.setStatus(rs.getBoolean("Status"));

   accountList.add(account);
}
```